# Remove pk in the loopback swagger

Tags: loopbackjs

In loopback, how could I remove the PK from the swagger json displayed.

This is the json displayed in my swagger:

```
{
  "user_id": "string",
  "order_type": "string",
  "date": "2016-04-28",
  "payload": {
    "id": 0
  },
  "id": 0
}
```

image detail- Swagger

[image: swagger]

how could I remove the "id": 0 ?

This is my order.json :

```
{
  "name": "Order",
  "plural": "Orders",
  "base": "Model",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "user_id": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "order_type": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "date": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true
    },
    "payload": {
      "type": "Payload",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

This is my order.js:

```
module.exports = (Order) => {

  Order.create = function(body, cb) {
   //
  }

  Order.remoteMethod('create', {
    'http': {'path': '/'},
    'accepts': [
      {'arg': 'body', 'type': 'Order', 'required': true, 'http': { 'source': 'body' } }
    ]
  });

};
```

Comment: You have `idInjection` enabled. If this is not what you want, disable it. You could also try hiding it in your model by adding a property `"id": false`.

Comment: idInjection made no effect

Answer (score 1):

Hidden property did the trick

```
{
  "name": "Order",
  "plural": "Orders",
  "base": "Model",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
     ...
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {},
  "hidden": ["id"]
}
```